# allowing users to dynamically spin up VMs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm not quite sure if this is the right place for this so let me know if it isn't.

I have an application that I run in VMs or on hardware for my clients. I'm looking to open the application to the public and allow anyone to spin up their own copy. My goal was to give anyone the ability to register an account on my website and spin up their own VM where they could use this application.

My initial plan was to use the AWS EC2 SDK to spin up the instance assign a static IP and boom off to the races. I didn't know, however, that you could only have a maximum of 5 IPs and 20 instances per region for a standard account. I figured there's no was around the IP address limit so I can use a proxy to direct traffic to the correct server but that still leaves me with my hard limit of 20 instances per region. Should I not use AWS for this use case? I guess I could setup one massive instance and use something like docker containers instead but I think that adds complexity that I don't need right now and if I need to go that route I might as well buy my own server and set it up in a colo. How would you recommend I need to set this up?

tl;dr
I need users to be able to spin up VMs through my website but don't know how to get around AWS limitations.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

Comment: You can request any number of IPs and instances, just fill out the appropriate request form and AWS will consider your request. If you're a new customer who's asking for huge limits they may want more information. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use virtualhosts to proxy URL's to the same IP over differnet ports? give differnet ports to each instance and use a virtualhost or similar to direct traffic to specific ones without needing new IP's. Instead of everyone being on 80 & 443 some users get different ports etc...